# Accepting managed struct in C++/CLI both with "hat" operator and without. What is the difference?

Tags: c++-cli

I've got a C++/CLI layer that I've been using successfully for a long time.  But I just discovered something that makes me think I need to relearn some stuff.

When my C++/CLI functions receive an instance of any managed **class**, they use the "hat" operator ('^') and when they receive an instance of a managed **struct**, they do not.  I thought this was how I was supposed to write it.

To illustrate as blandly as I can

```
using Point = System::Windows::Point;
public ref class CppCliClass
{
    String^ ReturnText(String^ text) { return text; }  // Hat operator for class
    Point   ReturnStruct(Point pt) { return pt; }      // No hat operator for struct
};
```

I thought this was required.  It certainly works.  But just today I discovered that CancellationToken is a struct, not a class.  My code accepts it with a hat.  I thought it was a class when I wrote it.  And this code works just fine.  My cancellations are honored in the C++/CLI layer.

```
void DoSomethingWithCancellation(CancellationToken^ token)
{
    // Code that uses the token.  It works just fine
}
```

So apparently I can choose either method.

But then what is the difference between passing in a struct by value (as I've done with every other struct type I use, like Point) and by reference (as I'm doing with CancellationToken?).  Is there a difference?

Comment: Big difference.  They should not have allowed this syntax, it gets far too many C++/CLI programmers into trouble.  Turning a value type value into a reference is possible,  the value gets boxed.  A boxing conversion creates the type system illusion that value types derive from System::Object.  The CLR has no direct support for it, the compiler emits the parameter type as System::ValueType.  Very inefficient, but you just can't tell in threaded code.  Only blows up loudly when there are function overloads, IntelliSense whispers when you try to call the function from C# or VB.NET.

Comment: Sounds like until now I've been mostly fortunate to have defaulted to the "no-hat" approach.  I will need to go through my API to make sure there aren't any others struct types I've passed this way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`^` for reference types and without for value types matches C#, but C++/CLI does give you more flexibility:

- Reference type without `^` is called "stack semantics" and automatically tries to call `IDisposable::Dispose` on the object at the end of the variable's lifetime.  It's like a C# `using` block, except more user-friendly.  In particular:

  - The syntax can be used whether the type implements `IDisposable` or not.  In C#, you can only write a `using` block if the type can be proved, at compile time, to implement `IDisposable`.  C++/CLI scoped resource management works fine in generic and polymorphic cases, where some of the objects do and some do not implement `IDisposable`.
  - The syntax can be used for class members, and automatically implements `IDisposable` on the containing class.  C# `using` blocks only work on local scopes.
- Value types used with `^` are boxed, but with the exact type tracked statically.  You'll get errors if a boxed value of a different type is passed in.